# Spring Boot unable to inject MapStruct into the container with the error : NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring-boot, maven, mapstruct

I am trying to use MapStruct in my Spring Boot project, but I am facing an issue injecting the MapStruct  defined classes into the container.

Error description :

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in dev.earl.order_owl.service.CustomerService required a bean of type 'dev.earl.order_owl.service.mapper.CustomerMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'dev.earl.order_owl.service.mapper.CustomerMapper' in your configuration.
```

CustomerMapper interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerDTO customerToCustomerDTO(Customer customer);
    Customer customerDTOToCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO);

    @Mapping(target = "customerNumber", ignore = true)
    CustomerDTO createCustomerDTOWithoutId(Customer customer);

}
```

CustomerService class that uses the mapper:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerService {

    private final CustomerRepository repository;
    private final CustomerMapper mapper;

    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository repository, CustomerMapper mapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public CustomerDTO getCustomer(Integer id) throws NullPointerException{
        Customer customer = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("customer cannot be found"));
        return this.mapper.customerToCustomerDTO(customer);

    }
```

I added @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") which I believe allows spring to discover this component and inject it into the container; however, it is not working as I expected. I belive it could also be an issue with my pom.xml and dependency itself. I am gettiing an error simply doing maven -clean

surefire-report generated by Maven:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.184 s <<< FAILURE! -- in dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplicationTests
dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplicationTests.contextLoads -- Time elapsed: 0.017 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1ec09a68 testClass = dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [dev.earl.order_owl.OrderOwlApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@7b4c50bc, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@491b9b8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@47caedad, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@37313c65, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@d57608fd], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [C:\Users\Earl\Desktop\SpringBoot_Projects\order_owl\order_owl\target\classes\dev\earl\order_owl\controller\CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'customerService' defined in file [C:\Users\Earl\Desktop\SpringBoot_Projects\order_owl\order_owl\target\classes\dev\earl\order_owl\service\CustomerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.earl.order_owl.service.mapper.CustomerMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService' defined in file [C:\Users\Earl\Desktop\SpringBoot_Projects\order_owl\order_owl\target\classes\dev\earl\order_owl\service\CustomerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.earl.order_owl.service.mapper.CustomerMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.earl.order_owl.service.mapper.CustomerMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 55 more
```

pom.xml depdency of mapstruct :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId> 
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Current design (injection via constructor) which is mostly the right way forces you to also satisfy spring definition. Another solution to the one you provided would be just do the mapping within a method, that would decouple mapper from the framework.

Injection via constructor is good approach, however in that particular case I would ask myself do I need to couple particular framework with just a mapper ? It requires you to do additional magic which seems slightly unnecessary and in terms of testing I think there won't be any difference.

```
    public CustomerDTO getCustomer(Integer id) throws NullPointerException {
    Customer customer = repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("customer cannot be found"));
    return CustomerMapper.INSTANCE.customerToCustomerDTO(customer);
}
```

Comment: You're right, depending on an external framework for simply generating mappings causes potential bugs and I have experienced that when changing fields within entities and DTOs. I'll keep in mind if it's even necessary considering the additional layer of complexity and magic it adds. Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading, I solved it by adding a maven-compiler-plugin and configuring my application to use lombok-mapstruct-bindings. For lombok to work with mapstruct, it takes an extra step or else mappings will not be generated.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.30</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0.Beta1</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- other annotation processors -->
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```